# Program memory not increasing when including math.h library

Tags: c, atmelstudio, attiny

I'm a bit of a newbie to the *Atmel* world. Once Upon a time I could write and compile C with *Visual Studio* but am a bit out of practice.

So I'm trying to get an understanding of memory usage in a microcontroller *ATTINY1616*.  I opened Atmel studios, created a C executable project and chose the correct microcontroller.  I build the project which has next to nothing in it and see that the program memory is `154 bytes`.  This is my baseline.

Now I tried to add the line `#include <math.h>` to see if my program memory usage would increase. It didn't.  Then I tried adding `float a = 2.000678f;` inside the `main`. Still no increases after building the project.  What am I misunderstanding here?

```
/*
* GccApplication2.c
*
* Created: 12/20/2018 9:21:43 PM
* Author : joely
*/ 

#include <avr/io.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void)
{ 
    float a = 2.000678f;
    /* Replace with your application code */
    while (1) 
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: The constant was probably optimized out, as you never use it in your program.

Comment: In these cases it is always useful to see the linker generated map file. Here you see for example what functions are required by your executable. It also contains information if functions or data has been truncated from the executable because they are not used. And many more.

Comment: Thanks for the comments.  I guess I assumed the compiler would find space in the microcontroller memory for me. Do I need to do something specific to save it to RAM for example?  Also, @ Johnny, I will try and find that to post later today.  Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Header files typically only contain **declarations** of functions, not the **definitions**.

You're not using any of the functions declared in math.h, so the library they reside in isn't getting linked into your program.  If you use one of them, for example `float b = sin(a)`, then the contents of the math library is required and is linked in (assuming you pass `-lm` to gcc to do so).

Comment: Using one routine from the math library should not necessarily link in “the contents of the math library.” It should link in a portion of the math library, which may or may not be partitioned into a number of object modules.

Comment: So I tried this the other night as well but with float b = atan(a); .  It still did not increase my program memory usage or my data memory usage.  I'm thinking that building the project is somehow not compiling the code, but when I have typos it throws errors.

Comment: Also in Atmel studios where would I add the "-lm" ? Build options? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

So after asking some friends with microcontroller experience I found the solution.

In Atmel Studio you need to go to Project-->Application Properties--->Toolchain and Change optimization to none.

Then it recognizes my floats and stores them in program memory, and when atan() is used to perform a calc it also fills up the space with the same above code.